# Show total sales in WooCommerce shop archives for each product

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have added this code to my website to show the number of product buy by my clients for each products of my store.

I would like to show the number of sales only if the product has been bought maybe 5 times (to never show "buy 0 time")…

So I have this code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'wpm_product_sold_count', 11 );

function wpm_product_sold_count() {
    global $product;
    $units_sold = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'total_sales', true );
    if ($units_sold > 5) {
        echo '<p class="sold-product">' . sprintf( __( 'Produit vendu: %s fois', 'woocommerce' ), $units_sold ) . '</p>';
    }
}
```

But it isn't working. Do you have any tips please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WooCommerce 3+ you can't acces anymore to the **`W_Product`** object properties like the product ID. You need to use the available methods, so **`$product->id`** don't work. 
Instead use the **`WC_Data get_id()`** method on it:

```
$product_id = $product->get_id();
```

For the product **total sales** use use directly the [**`WC_Product get_total_sales()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_total_sales) method this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'wpm_product_sold_count', 11 );

function wpm_product_sold_count() {
    global $product;

    $units_sold = $product->get_total_sales();
    if ($units_sold > 5) {
        echo '<p class="sold-product">' . sprintf( __( 'Produit vendu: %s fois', 'woocommerce' ), $units_sold ) . '</p>';
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested with woocommerce 3+ and works.